# VBA Filter on tables hides certain columns as well as rows. How can I stop this?

Tags: vba, excel

I am using VBA to filter a large data set by criteria in one of the columns. However, for some reason when I run the VBA columns Q-Y all become hidden. I cannot work out the reason for this. The cells aren't empty, nor is the column title empty. I then copy the visible cells and paste into another tab. So this is causing me issues.

The code I am using is quite simple:

```
   Sheets("Source").Range("$A$1:$Ad$1000000").AutoFilter Field:=28, Criteria1:= _
    "=work out*"
   myrange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
```

Can anyone explain where my formula is wrong? I would prefer not to have to add in the extra step of unhiding the hidden columns if I can.

Comment: Does the same happen manually?

Comment: No, it doesn't. It also only does it with data from the tables copied from a few files even though each of the files are formatted identically, with same column headings and data type etc.

Comment: Are `Q-Y` formulas built into the table? Or is it just straight data?

Comment: Straight data. Not even any formulas!